# Auto-complete mode (inside?) predictive mode & org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, auto-complete-mode, predictive-mode

There are many 'prediction' frameworks for emacs, I'm a bit puzzled as whether and how they integrate with one another.

I'm looking for something that learns words I type and predicts them. Also something that predicts org-mode syntacx. Maybe come C/C++ in the future.

I came across [AutoComplete](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) with [auto complete for org-mode](https://github.com/aki2o/org-ac).
Then there is also [predictive mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode) that appears to have an [auto complete mode](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Auto_002dCompletion-Mode.html#Auto_002dCompletion-Mode).

Now, does predictive mode actually make use of auto-complete, or is predictive's auto-complete different from the emacs/org-mode auto complete?

I.e, would I be able to configure predict mode to use autocomplete to auto-complete for org-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time I got a reply form the author.

It seem that autocomplete and predictive mode are seperate entities.

My question/reply:

```
Hi Leo,


On Wed, Mar 11, 2015 at 07:24:53PM -0400, Leo Ufimtsev wrote:
> Hello Toby,
>
> I've been reading up on predictive mode. I noticed it has a page related to auto-complete-mode.
>
> http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Auto_002dCompletion-Mode.html#Auto_002dCompletion-Mode
>
> Does this mean that it uses the emacs AutoComplete:
> http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete
>
> Or is that a different notion?

No, predictive-mode uses the auto-completion-mode from the Completion-UI
library, which is in many ways significantly more powerful than
AutoComplete. (In particular, in ways that are useful for predictive
completion.)

Best wishes,
Toby
-- 
Dr T. S. Cubitt
Royal Society University Research Fellow
Fellow of Churchill College, Cambridge
Quantum Information Theory group
DAMTP, University of Cambridge

email: tsc25@cantab.net
web:   www.dr-qubit.org
```